# SSRS: Report Exists but is not visible on Page

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am trying to upload a newly modified report to a Folder on our Report Server.

If I Upload with 'Overwrite Item if it Exists' checked, the Upload appears to execute.
But when I go to the destination page, the report does not appear there.

If I then try the Upload again - with 'Overwrite Item if it Exists' NOT checked, I get a message saying: "The folder, report, resource, model or data source /Folder_Name/Sub_Folder/Report_Name already exists."

The one thing I may have done that I have never done before is I may have first deleted the existing report from the destination folder before attempting to upload the modified replacement for it.

I need the modified report to be visible on the destination page/folder for my Users.

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!!

Comment: might sound obvious but have you tried refreshing the browser cache. If I deploy new reports and I the SSRS portal open, I have to fresh the page before it's visible.

Comment: @AlanSchofield: Thanks. I did try a View - Refresh a couple of times and even logged out of our system completely and then back in again. To no avail. Meanwhile, I created a New Folder and Uploaded the modified report to it - and moved all the other reports from the existing folder into the new folder. That has solved my immediate problem but I still don't know what happened. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Though I was not able to figure out why the modified report refused to show in the existing folder every time I uploaded it, I created a new folder and was able to upload the modified report into it and move all the other reports into the new folder as well. Everything is working as expected in the new folder. I know this is not an 'answer per se but it has solved my problem. Thanks!